# make an ADO.NET Dataview row ReadOnly

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataview

How do I make an ADO.NET Dataview row ReadOnly?  I tried the following with no success:

```
myDataView[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Do you have any other context that you can provide?

Comment: The grid should provide a mechanism whereby the user can add new entries to the DB and view but not edit pre-existing entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent edits but allow new rows to be added to the DataView by setting the following:

```
myDataView.AllowEdit = False;
myDataView.AllowNew = True;
```

[MSDN Article on modifying DataViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70k6287b.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like...

```
myDataGridView.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: I'm looking for DataView not DataGridView

Comment: You can set the readonly value for the entire view but I don't know of a way to set just one row.